# Delete record and show the next without full page reload?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I show an event by going to `/events/123`. If I delete the event I want to load the next available if it exists, otherwise redirect to `/events/`. Is the former possible without page reload? I tried this but I get a `404` (probably because I'm still on the deleted id and the url is not updated). I could do a full redirect and not sure if I'm making it harder for myself, but I have to solve some things in two different ways with notifications etc if I do a redirect so wanted to see if I can fix it by just loading a new record and update the url field.

```
public function submit()
{
    $this->event->delete();

    $event = Auth::user()->events()->first();

    $message = [
        'type' => 'success',
        'subject' => 'Event deleted',
        'message' => ''
    ];

    if ($event) {
        $this->event = $event;
        $this->emit('refreshEvents');
        $this->notify($message);
        // Update URL somehow?
    } else {
        session()->flash('message', $message);
        return redirect()->route('events');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if i got the question correctly , but you can do something like this

```
function show_event( $id )
{
    $event  = Event:findOrFail($id);
    return view('event-show' , compact('event'));
}

public function submit()
{
    $this->event->delete();

    $event = Auth::user()->events()->first();

    if ($event) {
    
        return $this->show_event( $event->id );
    
    } else {
        session()->flash('message', $message);
        return redirect()->route('events');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! And then in my render() run show_event()? Or is it in the mount()?

Comment: @SeaBass i assume you have a function to show a single event .... `/events/123` what is the function of this route ? lets call it `FunctionShowingSingleEvent`   and i assume that function is in the same controller .... so all you need is 

`return $this->FunctionShowingSingleEvent( $event->id );`

nothing else